# ClassNotFoundException when running jar but no issue while running the class

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker

I am getting a strange behaviour with my application.

From the IDE (Intellij), launching the main class is working fine.

When using

> mvn spring-boot:run

the app works fine as well.

But when trying to launch the application from the jar, I am getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
```

As my final objective is to have it working with Docker, I would like it to run with:

```
java -jar ./target/mail-business-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

After checking few posts, I checked the dependencies, removed the target folder so it can be recreated but the issue persists.

Would anyone have an idea? I am thinking about some dependencies compatibility but the tests I made so far were unsuccessful

Below is my pom.xl

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>mail-business</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.mail</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <dependencies>


        <!-- ===== Bibliothèques tierces ===== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.bval/bval-jsr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
            <artifactId>bval-jsr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>






            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>java/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.mail.impl.ScheduledTasks</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <!-- plugin 4- apache cxf codegen wsdl2java goal -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>generated/java</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>
                                        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xbreizh/troparo/e481ca9c19f78656678dfab01ca1a01f124c72e2/troparo-web/src/main/resources/org/troparo/web/services/MailService.wsdl
                                    </wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>
                                        https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xbreizh/troparo/e481ca9c19f78656678dfab01ca1a01f124c72e2/troparo-web/src/main/resources/org/troparo/web/services/ConnectService.wsdl
                                    </wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this locally and got it to work by adding this:

```
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and then running either 'install' or 'package' after a 'clean'.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html

Essentially, it looks like the plugin wasn't recreating your original jar. If you look in /target/, you should now see a .jar.original.

Comment: Nice one Hermann, works as you said. The jar is now executable. Many Thanks!